# ZF2 new module run step?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've spent 1-3 hours but I can't resolve my problem to run ZF2 module in my localhost
please suggest a solution to as me as I am a beginner of Zf2

I have download https://github.com/takeid/crunchysignup module(but i did not able run)
In my configuration of module step

```
Step -1 download from github then extracted then copy into zf2crud/module/crunchysignup
Step-> in C:\wamp\www\zf2crud\config\application.config.php file
```

added

```
  'module_paths' => array(
                    './module',
                    './vendor',
            './module/CrunchySignup'
             )





I run in my browse url like http://localhost/zf2crud/public/crunchysignup
```

My public index is running ok but this module url, I am getting an error like

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
No Exception available
```

Can anyone help me, what are these step? I can figure it out.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: can you check your routing in CrunchySignup -> module.config.php. Your routing should not start with slash(/), have to mention in your routing like this:http://localhost/zf2crud/public/crunchy-signup/

Comment: Hi @NgmAKumar router config contains  'route' => '/register',

Comment: In your options, you have mentioned  'route' => '/register', this will consider your module could be accessible from http://localhost/, but your modules are in http://localhost/zf2crud/modules/* To solve this issue, create a VirtualHost for your application.